# Different compiler behavior when applying a const qualifier to a template argument

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, clang, constants

Consider the following example ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/gzCzKi)):

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
const T *as_const(T *p) { return p; }

void f() {}

template <typename T>
void g(T *) { std::cout << "A"; }

template <typename T>
void g(const T *) { std::cout << "B"; }

int main() {
  g(as_const(&f));
}
```

Both GCC and Clang can compile it, but the resulting executables produce different output: the version compiled with GCC prints `A` and the one compiled with Clang prints `B`.

Could you explain this difference?

**Update**: as pointed out by @VTT the same difference is observed even if `as_const` is dropped.

Comment: I'm not sure what a pointer-to-const-function actually means or how it differs from a non-const-pointer-to-function.

Comment: [Can reproduce on this GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/737529ab9de74c17)

Comment: Visual studio outputs 'B'

Comment: [`as_const` is irrelevant for this example.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LeH2JXzyYlitiB4k)

Comment: Pretty sure you can't have pointers to `const` function types. See N4141 8.3.5/6 and 8.3.1/4.

Comment: @VTT, good catch, I thought this is a minimal example, but apparently the difference is there even without as_const.

Comment: Seems like you could assign a pointer to const function to a pointer to non-const function. `void(*ptr)() = as_const(&f);` seems fine. I guess the question is why there isn't an ambiguity between the `g` overloads.

Comment: Related, potential dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19131309/3002139

Comment: @BaummitAugen Note that if you remove the non-const `g` overload, then gcc actually fails to compile, which would be correct according to what you suggest. So I think this is just a bug in clang.

Comment: There is a correct answer on the dupe but it doesn't do it full justice. From my understanding of SO etiquette this question should be closed as a dupe, and Baum should post his answer citing the standard there (or even as an edit to one of the existing answers, which is basically correct).

Comment: Perhaps UB due to an ODR violation which the compilers cannot or don't bother to report because of the generic pointer argument? If you make the functions non-generic, then you get redefinition errors.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I don't undersatnd why you think that this is an ODR violation; the functions have two different signatures, and template deduction + overload rules will lead to exactly the intuitive behavior if you are working with pointers to objects (rather than to functions).

Comment: @NirFriedman: I believe you're correct and I misplaced the `const` qualifier.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It appears you hit a defect in the standard which has yet to be resolved. So the answer to "Which compiler is right?" would be not entirely clear currently.

The issue has been raised to and discussed by the committee:

> It is not clear whether the following is well-formed or not:
>
> ```
> void foo(){}
>
> template<class T>
> void deduce(const T*) { }
>
> int main() {
>   deduce(foo);
> }
> ```
>
> Implementations vary in their treatment of this example.

see http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1584, but the proposed resolution is not part of N4141 or N4659.

Note that you generally cannot have pointers to `const` function types; if you consider the example I quoted ill-formed, gcc would be correct. It does reject the example and, in the OP, picks the non-const version as the only viable overload.

If clang (which [claims to implement the proposed resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19287408/3002139)) would be right otherwise, I am not sure. I guess we'd have to revisit that discussion once the committee resolved the issue with some normative wording we can use.

However,

> The consensus of CWG was that the cv-qualification of the argument and parameter must match, so the original example should be rejected.

(note to said issue) seems to indicate that gcc is right and the issue will be resolved in favor of its behavior.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning explicitly that gcc does in fact fail to compile that example; gcc could in principle give the non-const `g` priority, but still compile the const qualified pointer version if the other were unavailable.